# Как сделать тень для png или svg drawable по контуру?

Tags: android, svg, png

Необходимо отбросить тень от элемента `view`. Есть картинка в svg и png формате. Но не получается сделать это корректно.

Вариант без тени:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант с тенью который необходимо получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам необходимо добавить в вопрос код SVG. Уверен, что после добавления кода быстро получите ответ, как добавить тень.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно мои данные устарели, но вроде программно - никак. Elevation дает тень только на паре шейпов из drawable, и то на некоторых не так, как на остальных. Андроднцый svg не поддерживает никаких теней. Градиентом можно нарисовать тень для объекта с ровными краями, но в вашем случае - нет. Остается только один вариант - рисовать тень в png вместе с самим элементом